# Moving a Picture or clock on the wall

Tags: muktzeh

Are you allowed to move a picture or clock on the wall on Shabbos if it is or it is not of great value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that a person sets aside in a fixed place because of its great value,
and they are strict not to move it in order it should not get damaged (for example a wall clock or a painting that one is particular about) is also included in
Muktza Machmas Chisaron Kis, and you are not allowed to move it on Shabbos.

Footnote 67: According to the opinion of the Chazon Ish it seems that even if the painting or picture is not valuable, but one doesn’t move it because it is hung on the wall, it is also considered Muktza Machmas Chisaron Kis.Reb Moshe Feinstein Disagrees and says it is allowed.

Shmiras Shabbos K’Hilchoso 20:22